# Open activity or dialog box when i press image i have in my viewPAger

Tags: android, android-viewpager

in My root Activity i have Slide show that displayed by the VIewPager .
in my case i want to open new activity or dialog box or something like this when i pressed image on Slide show .
Normally i used `OnclickListener` and assign picture id to it and don't get any Feedback .

### RootActivity.java

```
    public class RootActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_root);

        // Image slide show 
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        ImageAdapter.setTimer(viewPager, 3, 0);
         // End Image slide show

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.drawable.ax1);
        vp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.print("OK ...");

            }
        });
}

}
```

### ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    final static Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static Timer swipeTimer ;
    Context context;
    private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three,
        R.drawable.ax1,
        R.drawable.ax2,
    };
    ImageAdapter(Context countDownTimer){
        this.context=countDownTimer;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);

    }


    public static void setTimer(final ViewPager myPager, int time, final int curPage){

        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            int NUM_PAGES =5;
            int currentPage = curPage ;
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES ) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                myPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };

        swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 1000, time*1000);

}
}
```

Comment: Directly set `onClickListener(...)` to your `ImageView` in your `ImageAdapter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, first things first...

**1.** This line, in `RootActivity.onCreate()` does not make a lot of sense:

`ViewPager vp = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.drawable.ax1);`

You're trying to find a ViewPager object in the layout using a drawable resource id. So delete this line and everything in `onCreate()` that comes after it.

**2.** You can only attach an `OnClickListener` to an existing view and since there is no OnItemClickListener for PagerAdapters, you need to attach the `OnClickListener` to the appropriate Views from within the Adapter's `instantiateItem()` method.

***I have attached a modified version of your code representing these points.***

## RootActivity.java

```
public class RootActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_root);
        // Image slide show
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        ImageAdapter.setTimer(viewPager, 3, 0);
        // End Image slide show
    }
}
```

## ImageAdapter.java

*Look for the* `// Begin Added by SpaceLord` *comments*

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    final static Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static Timer swipeTimer;
    Context context;
    private int[] GalImages = new int[]{
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.two,
            R.drawable.three,
            R.drawable.ax1,
            R.drawable.ax2,
    };

    ImageAdapter(Context countDownTimer) {
        this.context = countDownTimer;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);

        // Begin Added by SpaceLord
        imageView.setOnClickListener(itemClickListener);
        imageView.setTag(position);
        // End Added by SpaceLord

        container.addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    // Begin Added by SpaceLord
    private final View.OnClickListener itemClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int tag = (Integer) v.getTag();
            switch (tag) {
                // Do whatever you need to for each slide click here
                case 0:
                    Log.d(ImageAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), "Clicked on ONE");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Log.d(ImageAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), "Clicked on TWO");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Log.d(ImageAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), "Clicked on THREE");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Log.d(ImageAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), "Clicked on AX1");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Log.d(ImageAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), "Clicked on AX2");
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    // End Added by SpaceLord

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((ImageView) object);

    }


    public static void setTimer(final ViewPager myPager, int time, final int curPage) {

        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            int NUM_PAGES = 5;
            int currentPage = curPage;

            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                myPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };

        swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 1000, time * 1000);

    }
}
```

Comment: can i add intent for open new activity in switch case ?

Comment: Yes. `context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NextActivity.class));` - Just replace NextActivity with your own.

Answer (score 2):

Directly set `onClickListener(...)` to your `ImageView` in your `ImageAdapter` like:

```
 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
  int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
  imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
  imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);

  imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          //Do your job

        }
    });

  ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
  return imageView;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I want to show what each picture individually.how do you make this Separation ?